# Encryption with own Cipher Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, encryption, python-3.4

Here is my code:

```
dictionary = {'A':'3',
'B':'u',
'C':'t',
'D':'5',
'E':'b',
'F':'6',
'G':'7',
'H':'8',
'I':'/',
'J':'9',
'K':'0',
'L':'-',
'M':'o',
'N':'i',
'O':';',
'P':'}',
'Q':'c',
'R':'n',
'S':'4',
'T':'m',
'U':'.',
'V':'y', 
'W':'v',
'X':'r', 
'Y':',',
'Z':'e',
}
print(dictionary)
inp = input(str("What do you want me to encode?").upper()).upper()
li = list(inp)
print(li)
for letter in inp:
    pass
```

I want to ask how I could use this dictionary to encrypt any message that goes through the input. Like 'Hello my name is Jerry' would turn into: (Without Phrasing) '8b--; o, i3ob /4 9bnn,'.
Could someone please help me with this. Ive seen other questions like this being asked - but they use PyCrypto. I dont want to go through the hassle of installing it. Could someone please help me.

Thanks,
Jerry

Comment: BTW this code is entirely new - there is a lot more to it than what I put here - but the shell would print an error if I  included it. My friend created a mathematical one. Much easier to code though.

Comment: Check if all modules are imported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass each character of the user input through the dictionary to get the cypher value out.

```
# removed the first .upper() here
inp = input(str("What do you want me to encode?")).upper()
li = list(inp)
print(li)

# create a list of letters passed through the dictionary
out = [dictionary[letter] for letter in inp]

# using ''.join makes the new list a single string
print(''.join(out))
```

Comment: I am getting an error @James where I put in some text: Hello My and an error comes saying: Invalid Syntax. Why does it do this? I want the encrypt-er to be able to do multiple words

Comment: On second though -  this answer is enough. I can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.translate` method. The benefit here is that you only have to create the table once, so you can use the same table even if you have lots of strings to encrypt.

```
table = str.maketrans(dictionary) # create a translate table

inp = input("What do you want me to encode? ").upper()
res = inp.translate(table)
print(res)
```